# change from button to submit

Tags: jquery

```
<a id="t-1">Details - 1</a>
<a id="t-2">Details - 2</a>
<a id="t-3">Details - 3</a>
```

and there are 3 buttons

```
<input type="button" name="submit-1" id="submit-1">
<input type="button" name="submit-2" id="submit-2">
<input type="button" name="submit-3" id="submit-3">
```

Now when I click any other the link, I need to change type of button to submit

For example, if I click with id "t-1", the input type of "submit-1" should change from button to submit

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: Whatever you are trying to accomplish, make sure it won't break if the user is able to submit the form without the submit button (e.g., hitting `Enter`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("a[id^='t-']").click(function(){
   var buttonId = this.id;
   document.getElementById('submit-' + buttonId).setAttribute('type','submit');
});
```

Comment: error Uncaught TypeError: Object #submit-3 has no method 'attr'